# How can I "downgrade" gstreamer?

Tags: 10.04, rhythmbox, gstreamer, downgrade

I use Ubuntu 10.04.

Ever since I updated gstreamer, Movie Player doesn't work properly anymore and neither does Rhythmbox.

How can I keep using the previous version of gstreamer that worked?

Answer (score 2):

To downgrade a package go to Synaptic Package Manager. Find which package you want to downgrade. Select it. Then in the menu, go to Package -> Force Version...

Then you would be able to select which version.

You can also do it in cli, for example:

sudo apt-cache showpkg gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio

It will show the depencies and after Provides will show the versions:
0.10.21-1ubuntu3 - gstreamer0.10-audiosource gstreamer0.10-audiosink 
0.10.21-1ubuntu2 - gstreamer0.10-audiosource gstreamer0.10-audiosink

Then you can downgrade:
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio=0.10.21-1ubuntu2

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't solve my problem. :-\

I'll try to find a solution by myself for this.

Still, thanks a lot.

Comment: he just answered what you asked: 'how to downgrade'. Want to solve your problem¿ Make a question describin your problem and give us details like the error messages or the terminal output

Answer (score 0):

Works on **Lubuntu 18.04 LTS** with this:

> `sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-qapt=3.0.4-0ubuntu1`